# How to install Extension manually, ignoring certificate warnings?

Tags: extension, stripe

I tried to install the Stripe extension a short while ago, but the website hosting the extension has an expired SSL certificate, so CiviCRM gave me an error:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

60
```

I've now downloaded the file manually and placed the folder in my Extensions directory, but I still can't install, I get the same error.

Is there a method to install overriding this warning?

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete `com.drastikbydesign.stripe.xml` from the `civicrm_extensions/cache` folder, then use the Refresh button on the Extensions page.

Only then did it pick up that the Stripe Extension folder had been copied locally (rather than remote), and let me install manually.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question.  Why not mark this as the accepted answer so that other people know that this worked for you.

Comment: Because Stack Exchange does not let me tick it

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Apparently you have to wait 48 hours to do this.